# Order of elements with the same priority in std::priority_queue

Tags: c++, stl, queue, priority-queue

I have following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <list>
#include <queue>
#include <memory>

enum class CommandType : uint8_t {
  Comm1,
  Comm2, 
  Comm3, 
  Comm4, 
  Comm5 
};

enum class Priority {
  HIGH,
  MEDIUM, 
  LOW
};

std::map<CommandType, Priority> priorities = {
    { CommandType::Comm1, Priority::LOW }, 
    { CommandType::Comm2, Priority::LOW }, 
    { CommandType::Comm3, Priority::LOW }, 
    { CommandType::Comm4, Priority::LOW }, 
    { CommandType::Comm5, Priority::LOW }
};

class QueueEntry 
{
 public:
    QueueEntry(CommandType type)
        : type_(type) {}
    CommandType getType() { return type_; }

private:
  CommandType type_;
};

struct QueueEntryPriorityComparator  {
    bool operator()(std::unique_ptr<QueueEntry>& entry1, std::unique_ptr<QueueEntry>& entry2) const
    {
        auto p1 = priorities.at(entry1->getType());
        auto p2 = priorities.at(entry2->getType());

        return p1 < p2;
    }
};

std::priority_queue<std::unique_ptr<QueueEntry>, std::deque<std::unique_ptr<QueueEntry>>, QueueEntryPriorityComparator> q;

void print()
{
    decltype(q) queueCopy;
    queueCopy.swap(q);

    while (!queueCopy.empty()) {
        auto& top = queueCopy.top();

        std::cout << "Command type: " << static_cast<uint32_t>(top->getType()) << std::endl;;

        q.emplace(std::make_unique<QueueEntry>(top->getType()));

        queueCopy.pop();
    }
}

int main()
{


    q.emplace(std::make_unique<QueueEntry>(CommandType::Comm1));
    q.emplace(std::make_unique<QueueEntry>(CommandType::Comm2));
    q.emplace(std::make_unique<QueueEntry>(CommandType::Comm3));
    q.emplace(std::make_unique<QueueEntry>(CommandType::Comm4));
    q.emplace(std::make_unique<QueueEntry>(CommandType::Comm5));

    print();

    std::cout << std::endl;

    print();

    std::cout << std::endl;

    print();



    return 0;
}
```

Each element has the same priority which is `Priority::LOW`;

The question is, how those elements are placed in `priority_queue`?

Whenever I print the queue, elements are in different positions.
It is important to me that, if any new element comes to priority_queue should be placed after the last element with the same priority.

Can it be achieved by using `std::priority_queue` or I must wrap it on my own?

Comment: Nothing in the specification of priority_queue tells how elements with the same priority are sorted. You have to add information on your data and define a new ordering to take into account insertion order.

Comment: If you want newer elements with the same priority to have a lower priority, they don’t really have the same priority, do they?

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes they do. I find it intuitive that FIFO order is kept, that's the definition of queue, after all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The question is, how those elements are placed in priority_queue?

In an order that satisfies the heap property. Which for equal elements is *any* order.

> It is importatnt to me that, if any new element comes to priority_queue should be placed after the last element with the same priority.

You can achieve that by making the order part of the priority. But to make it part of the priorty, you need to first make the order part of the element. You can use a running counter:

```
struct OrderedQueueEntry {
    QueueEntry entry;
    int index;
};

struct OrderedQueueEntryPriorityComparator  {
    bool operator()(std::unique_ptr<OrderedQueueEntry>& left, std::unique_ptr<OrderedQueueEntry>& right) const
    {
        auto pl = priorities.at(left->entry.getType());
        auto pr = priorities.at(right->entry.getType());

        return pl == pr
            ? left->index < right->index;
            : pl < pr;
    }
};

int i = 0;
q.emplace(std::make_unique<OrderedQueueEntry>({CommandType::Comm1, i++}));
q.emplace(std::make_unique<OrderedQueueEntry>({CommandType::Comm2, i++}));
q.emplace(std::make_unique<OrderedQueueEntry>({CommandType::Comm3, i++}));
q.emplace(std::make_unique<OrderedQueueEntry>({CommandType::Comm4, i++}));
q.emplace(std::make_unique<OrderedQueueEntry>({CommandType::Comm5, i++}));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a priority queue guaranteeing that equal-comparing elements preserve insertion order, you need to write it yourself.

Certainly [`std::priority_queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) does not guarantee this insertion ordering (and if it's implemented as a heap, that doesn't guarantee it either).

The easiest way to write *something* correct is probably with `map<key, list<val>>`, although that's probably not ideal if you need it to be fast. The suggestion to manually `stable_sort` a container has worse algorithmic complexity but probably performs better in most real-world situations despite that.

Answer (score 1):

### Use a `std::multiset` or `std::multimap`

Just use `std::multiset` or `std::multimap` (from your case the `multimap` looks like the right choice).

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap

Both is *staple* and does not change the insertion order (since [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)).

Answer (score 0):

`std::priority_queue` is implemented by using [`std::make_heap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap), [`std::push_heap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/push_heap), and [`std::pop_heap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/pop_heap) on the underlying container.  These operations are not stable so you get no guarantee that elements will stay in entered order.

If you need them to stay in entered order then one thing you can do is to write you own object that uses [`std::stable_sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort) on the underlying container when adding elements into it.